# Why does going close to absolute zero take out friction?

Tags: temperature, viscosity, superfluidity, cryogenics

I read in a physics book that when you get close to absolute zero, a liquid stops having friction. Why is that (if it’s even true, that is)?

Comment: The concepts you need here are called viscosity and superfluidity; Wikipedia will give you a start. Most liquids freeze before zero is attained. Helium at atmospheric pressure is the most well-known example which stays liquid, and becomes superfluid near absolute zero.